# Is there any way to make non-html5 supporting browsers to support html5, not just the html5 markup, html5 api's as well?

Tags: javascript, html

Specifically i want to make the non-html5 browser to support html5 geolocation api atleast.

Comment: I think there is, using some server side language like PHP..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one other option . You can use google's fallback api  , this way you could let google handle the geolocation call for you via clientLocation  . I found this link :

http://marcgrabanski.com/html5-geolocation-fallback-google-ajax-api/

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to magically make non-html5 browsers support html5, unless you volunteer to modify the application and add support. :) However, there are workarounds for most html5-only apis and features.

In your case, depending on what you plan on doing, you could try using geoPlugin (http://www.geoplugin.com/) or Bing's GeoLocationProvider class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125833.aspx). More information and context on your case would help us help you better.

Comment: Why to re-invent the wheel if something already exists or there is a way around. Of course it is a magic when it is a new invention before the world :)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any way to do this. Browsers that don't support HTMl5 don't support it, it's like trying to get Microsoft word to display a webpage, it isn't designed to do it.

Comment: Well, we have html5-shiv which actually makes Microsoft word like old browser to render the HTML5 tags even though it is not designed to do it :)